# Laravel 3 routing all "/" requests to a specific group of controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a main site (/site) and two hotsites (/market, /content) and 1 admin (/admin). Now I can only access the main site using localhost/site/controller, but I wanna to route all "/" requests to the main site.

For instance:

```
localhost/login -> localhost/site/login
```

The same is valid for GET and POST requests.

Any tips ?

I've tried with wildcard in laravel routes without luck.

Comment: Are these 4 separate Laravel installs?  Or all the same laravel install with multiple controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::any('/(:any)/(:all)', function($site, $route)
{
    return Redirect::to('site/'.$route);
});
```

I think something like this should work. Make sure it's at the bottom of your `routes.php` because routes are evaluated in the order they are registered.